# Google Sheets Query | Use aggregation function count() in where clause

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Say I've got a list of names in column A.

- Chandler
- Ross
- Monika
- Joey
- Phoebe
- Rachel
- Ross
- Monika
- Joey
- Ross
- Monika
- Joey

Entering the below formula, produces the below result 
=query(A:A, "select A, count(A) group by A")

|  | count |
| --- | --- |
| Chandler | 1 |
| Joey | 3 |
| Monika | 3 |
| Phoebe | 1 |
| Rachel | 1 |
| Ross | 3 |

Can I somehow make the below formula work and produce the below table? 
=query(A:A, "select A, count(A) where count(A)>2 group by A")

|  | count |
| --- | --- |
| Joey | 3 |
| Monika | 3 |
| Ross | 3 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add aggregate function to `WHERE` clause, so using one query it is not possible. But you can add another `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(query(A:A, "select A, count(A) group by A"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2>2")
```

[image]